# Why Infinity == Infinity == 1/0 is false?

Tags: javascript, infinity

The question is quite simple:

```
Infinity == Infinity
>> true

Infinity == 1/0
>> true

Infinity == Infinity == 1/0
>> false
```

Why the last evaluation is `false`?

Comment: `Infinity == Infinity == 1/0` → `(Infinity == Infinity) == 1/0` → `true == 1/0` ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Associativity))

Comment: `Infininty == 1/0` evaluates to `true`, so `Infinity == true` evaluates to false.
It would be the same if you evaluated `Infinity == Infinity` first and the result is `true` and then `true == 1/0` is `false`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `Infinity == Infinity == 1/0` is basically

```
(Infinity == Infinity) == 1/0
```

so

```
(true) == 1/0
```

is `false`.

Comment: It's exactly the same with any other types: `"a" == "a" == "a"` results in `false`

Comment: but it's not true for `1 == 1 == 1`

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Because `1 == 1` is true and `true == 1` however `true !== 1`. It's the difference between strict and lose comparison.

Answer (score 0):

its look trying like below..

```
var d = (2 == 2);
console.log(d) //true
console.log(d == 2); //[true == 2] false
```

> > comparison **==** return always boolean `true or false`[`1 or 0`]